# Import Activity is failing

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

Am getting this error in the import activity
Results:

```
    Inserted: 0
```

Warnings:

```
    Warning: Import aborted while processing Batch 10 in DsvFileSourceReader. One or more errors indicating why the import was aborted may be logged to the dbo.ImportError table.
```

No idea how to fix this.